# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

Tags: android, arrays

Trying to find out were I'm going wrong with this piece of code as I receive ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions on this line `.elementAt(spriteIdx);`. Thanks for the tip.

Jason

```
Play = new Sprite[8][13];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                int spriteIdx = map.getInt(String.format("play-%d-%d", i, j));
                if (spriteIdx != -1) {
                    Play[i][j] = (Sprite) savedSprites
                            .elementAt(spriteIdx);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have empty `saveSprites` array.

Comment: Hi so a simple chech condition if sprites ! = 0 should fix it?

Comment: if (sprites !=null && sprites.lenght > 0)